# I have 32 GB external, but my internal is only 4GB!

Tags: samsung, insufficient-memory

My mom bought me a phone. It's Samsung Galaxy J1. And It says that it has only 4GB in my internal storage. But I have 32 GB external storage.

So, I downloaded all apps that I wanted then I  moved it all (that can moved)to the external storage.

But when I tried to download a new app, it says that my internal storage is full! And now, I can't download some apps nor pictures and music.

Yes, I do have a lot of space left in my external memory. But it looks like nothing because it's useless now.

So please, help me from my problem. And w/o rooting my phone. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not unusual to have more external than internal memory. I once had a 2Gb tablet with 64Gb SD card. I By what means did you "move" them to external storage? Can you be sure you didn't actually "copy" them? How much internal space did you free up in performing this move? 4Gb is a LOT of internal storage! It really should be plenty on its own, unless you're downloading the whole Google play store!

Comment: Please check with our [insufficient-memory tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info) to get started on the topic. It feels like this question is asked at least once per day, so additionally there should be plenty other questions using that tag.

Comment: Check the installed apps how many space they consume. As you have a cheap phone with small memory you have to manage your apps: only install apps you really need.

Comment: [How disk space is used on Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/216132/218526)

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view, the best solution is to root Your phone and install Links2SD or App2SD ROOT PRO form Play Store. If rooting is not avaliable (lost of guarantee) please use App2SD for non-root users. There is a lot of such apps in Play Store. It moves parts of apps to SD card and frees space in internal memory.
But if You root Your device, all app parts can be moved to SD, even part of system apps.